# CSS anchor link with borders and triangle click area

Tags: css

I have this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6953ugj4/

My actual code looks like this:

```
 <section class="tile-column large-8 columns min-height" tile-column>
     <h1 class="column-title">Order lines</h1>

     <div class="loading black" ng-show="controller.order.loading"></div>

     <div class="alert alert-box" ng-show="!controller.order.loading && !controller.order.data">
         No records have been found that match your search.
         <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
     </div>

     <div class="tile large box-shadow" ng-repeat="line in controller.order.data.lines" coloured-tile>
         <a class="action-button">
            <div class="triangle">
                <div class="action-tick">

                </div>
             </div>
         </a>

         <div class="text">
             <p>
                 <strong>{{ line.id }}</strong> {{ line.referenceNumber | limitTo: 7 }}
                 <span class="pull-right"><strong>{{ line.stockQuantity }} M</strong> {{ line.unitOfMeasure === 0 && line.type === 0 ? 'Cut' : 'Roll' }}</span><br />
                 <strong>{{ line.sku }}</strong> <span ng-show="line.colourMatchId">Matched to {{ line.colourMatchId }}</span><br />
                 <strong>{{ line.currency.code }}{{ line.currency.lineValue }}</strong> {{ line.currency.code }}{{ line.currency.unitPrice }} M<sup>2</sup><br />
                 <strong>{{ line.dates.delivery | date : 'mediumDate' }}</strong> For {{ line.forDelivery ? 'Delivery' : 'Collection' }}
             </p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

What I am trying to do is create a link that sits over the top of the **tile** and is selectable. But I want the border and the triangle to be click-able. At the moment, the only thing that is click-able is the border of the link.
How can I make the triangle click-able?

Also, in my project the border is inside the **tile** and fits perfectly, so some reason on the fiddle it truncates the bottom border. Not sure why.

Comment: So `.triangle` should be clickable and the rest shouldn't ? Because if you set the `href` attribute for the `.action-title` element, you'll get a full clickable box.

Comment: triangle and the border of .action-button should be click-able. Not sure what .action-title is :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the border and the triangle to be clickable but not the content.

You can do this by adding an additional element and placing it **above** the the anchor (which has the light-blue border) but **below** the triangle (which is within the anchor)

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6953ugj4/5/)

```css
.tile-content {
  width: 190px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.action-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.action-button .triangle .action-tick {
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font: normal normal normal 25px/1 FontAwesome;
  color: white;
}
.action-button .triangle .action-tick:before {
  content: "\f00c";
}
.action-button .triangle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 50px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <div class="tile-content"></div>
  <a class="action-button" href="#">
    <div class="triangle">
      <div class="action-tick">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```